# ConTeXt no bottom titles

Tags: context

guys am learning all about ConTeXt and i've a question:
What is the equivalent ConTeXt command to "\usepackage[nobottomtitles]{titlesec}" in LaTeX?

Answer (score 3):

Normally, the various penalties in ConTeXt are set in such a way that a page break after a section title is discouraged, but there are times when a page break is introduced after a section head because not doing so may result in a poorer page break (as evaluated by TeX).

However, if you don't want a page break after a section head, you can use

```
\setuphead[before={\blank\testpage[4]}]
```

The `\testpage[4]` command checks if there is enough space to include 4 lines; if not, it introduces a page break. I used a value of `4` assuming that some titles could span multiple lines. You can experiment with `\testpage[3]` or even  `\testpage[2]` to see if those work better in your setup.